# Associate multiple class mappings with a given context map id

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dozer

I am specifying mappings for Dozer as the following code shows but I get this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate Map Id's Found.`. I understand what is wrong but what I want is to have one set of mappings for the admin context and another for user context. Can't this be done? Do I have to write dogAdmin, catAdmin etc as map-id?

```
<mapping map-id="admin">
    <class-a>Cat</class-a>
    <class-b>CatView</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>name</a>
        <b>firstName</b>
    </field>
</mapping>

<mapping map-id="admin">
    <class-a>Dog</class-a>
    <class-b>DogView</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>name</a>
        <b>firstName</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, you can't do that, I tried too.